# Struts2 and Jersey in single web application produces http 500 error

Tags: struts2, jersey

It shows http 500 with jasper error, while launching the application, Im using jersey and struts2 in same project. Any particular configuration is required. Eventhough, all jar files are included, it shows error.

Web.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>RestExample</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.src.matchmaker.services</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">


<struts>
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/rest/.*" />

    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">


    </package>
</struts>
```

login.jsp

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : register
    Created on : Jan 31, 2013, 11:18:43 AM
    Author     : wifin
![enter image description here][1]--%>

<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/match_login_style.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/logo.jpg"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery.validation.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/login_validation.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="back" align="center">
                <form id="login" name="login" action="login.action" method="post">
                    <div align="center" class="header">Login</div>
                    <div id="err"><s:actionerror/></div>
                    <div class="tit">
                        Email Id: <input type="text" name="emailId" id="emailId"/>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tit">
                        Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div> 
                        <input class="btn" type="submit" name="reg" value="Login" id="reg" />
                        <input class="btn" type="reset" value="Cancel" id="cancel" />
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div><a class="link" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/register.jsp">New User?</a></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing root cause
The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]

Answer (score 0):

You page is being displayed without going through Struts2 filter. You need to call Struts2 action which will display your page as a result.

Also the `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher` is deprecated since Struts 2.1.3, so if you are using version greater then 2.1.3 change FilterDispatcher to `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`.

Also why not to intercept all url patterns with this filter? Change this filter `<url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`.

BTW using scriptlets in JSP is a bad practice, use Struts2 tags instead.